# VoIP + Ruby on Rails web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, voip

I have a project written in Ruby on Rails 2.1.

There a login & password needed to pass to my site (user & admins i have). Simple web-site.

But i want to create button "CALL ME". If i click on this button user can talk with (for example) admins.

What i need for this? Maybe some tools or already created apps?

P.S I can have my own voip server. (but is it necessary?))

Answer (score 0):

There are 'livechat' text based services out there - most 'Call Me' features I've seen simply get a few details from the visitor which generates an email to internal staff to call the user back - works for out of hours too :)